# Unable to Install STRAPI, on the Latest LTS of NODE.js, Either using NPM or YARN

Tags: node.js, backend, strapi, headless-cms

I installed Latest **LTS(v18.12.1)** of NODE.Js on my system; My **NPM version(8.19.2)**; **YARN version(3.3.1)**.

And I am unable to install the STRAPI, According the the [Strapi Website](https://strapi.io/)
to start the Strapi Backend you need to run this command `npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart`

I get the following error.
[My Terminal Screenshot of Strapi Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGNL0.png).

After the error I tried to go in 'my-project' directory and run `yarn install`, According the the error message, But Still got the same error.

then I tried to do a fresh new installation using yarn command `yarn create strapi-app my-project`
Still the same error.

I expected that after running the command my Strapi Backend should create in 'my-project' folder.
Am I doing something wrong?

---

Note that I am using it locally, Other similar questions are about using on google cloud and VPS, and my node version is also different.

Answer (score 0):

This issue below is registered a bit later since you've post this question, but it prints out same error message. I'm also having a hard time with this problem too. It seems like we need to wait a bit for this issue to be solved.

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/15964

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34363197)